# Why is google maps not zooming on the Lat/Long I provide?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented the Google Maps API v2 in my Android app. I add a marker and zoom to level 14 when I open the activity containing the map fragment.

Here is how I add/update the marker:

```
private void updateMarker() {
    if(marker != null){
        marker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(username));
    marker.setIcon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom), 2000, null);
}
```

It works correctly in debug via Android Studio, using a Nexus 5 with the latest Android installed. The problem is when I run a release build. The marker is added in the correct place, the zoom animation works correctly, zooming to the correct level. But it doesn't move to the marker I added.

Comment: try passing `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom);` to `animateCamera`

Comment: What are your coordinates ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Your suggestion was correct, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should pass the result value of   `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom)` to `animateCamera` which returns  a `CameraUpdate` that moves the center of the screen to a latitude and longitude specified by a `LatLng` object, and moves to the given zoom level. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngZoom(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float))

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom));
```

Or

```
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom), 2000, null);
```

Don't call both method right after each other.

Comment: What is 2000 for?

Comment: Animation duration in millis.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and override `onConnected` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mGMLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGMGoogleApiClient);

    try {
        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSEnabled)  
        {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            //You can still do this if you like, you might get lucky
            mGMLastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (mGMLastKnownLocation != null) {
                //place marker at current position
                mMap.clear();

                // Get latitude of the current location
                double latitude = mGMLastKnownLocation.getLatitude();

                // Get longitude of the current location
                double longitude = mGMLastKnownLocation.getLongitude();

                // Create a LatLng object for the current location
                latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                // Show the current location in Google Map
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Zoom in the Google Map
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7));

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                mCurrLocation = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            } else {
                mGMLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                mGMLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
                mGMLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
                mGMLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGMGoogleApiClient, mGMLocationRequest, this);
            }

        } else {
            //prompt user to enable location

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

}
```

Also, implement `LocationListener` and override the `onLocationChanged` method as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //remove previous current location marker and add new one at current position
    if (mCurrLocation != null) {
        mCurrLocation.remove();
    }

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Position").snippet("I am here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
    mCurrLocation = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //If you only need one location, unregister the listener
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGMGoogleApiClient, this);


}
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: I don't see any point marking it negative. I have tested this code and it works fine. Please explain.